# Locked-NVram detected

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

Ubuntu 20.10

I have a gpt /dev/sda.

run boot-repair and I got this:

```
WindowsEFI detected. Please disable BIOS-compatibility/CSM/Legacy mode in your UEFI firmware, and use this software from a live-CD (or live-USB) that is compatible with UEFI booting mode. For example, use a live-USB of Boot-Repair-Disk-64bit (www.sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd), after making sure your BIOS is set up to boot USB in EFI mode.
```

booted from USB and I got this:

Boot-repair-disk can't repair: Locked-NVram detected

[image]

Comment: This is a hardware error and you will not be able to fix it from Ubuntu https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=327158 suggests resetting cmos jumpers.

Comment: perhaps this is related to segfault I have on some software. BIOS also not saving changes thus I am stuck with legacy. CMOS battery replaced but did not change anything. I shorted the CMOS jumper but nothing change. Tried to flashbios but failed. What else? Thanks btw!