# Locked NVram in dual booted Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I dual booted my HP laptop with Ubuntu today and everything was working fine. Later I booted into Windows 11 and restarted the laptop and the grub no longer shows up. So I checked the UEFI boot order and only windows was in it. There was no Ubuntu. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu but the same issue came back. Then I ran boot repair from a live usb and it showed a locked NVram issue which I have no idea about. I have included boot-repair summary below.

```
boot-repair-4ppa203                                             [20221223_1601]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================






Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p8,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file


Mount nvme0n1p1 on /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p8/etc/default/grub

===================== Reinstall the grub-efi of nvme0n1p8 ======================

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7
chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 modprobe efivars

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 efibootmgr -v before grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,a0959a8d-d457-4c76-afe4-7c1a16d270ba,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0001* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(5,GPT,8ab946cd-87d7-6545-9d2e-958aa76179f2,0x2bad1800,0x96000)..BO
Boot0003* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(6,GPT,22c6d891-2c8f-4e31-8dff-54b06692e8a7,0x3a94b800,0x3e7fff)..BO
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f091577,0x800,0x3956800)..BO

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 uname -r
5.15.0-43-generic

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p1
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p5
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
df /dev/nvme0n1p6
mv /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8/boot/efi/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: warning: EFI variables cannot be set on this system.
grub-install: warning: You will have to complete the GRUB setup manually.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 efibootmgr -v after grub install
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,a0959a8d-d457-4c76-afe4-7c1a16d270ba,0x800,0x82000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0001* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(5,GPT,8ab946cd-87d7-6545-9d2e-958aa76179f2,0x2bad1800,0x96000)..BO
Boot0003* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(6,GPT,22c6d891-2c8f-4e31-8dff-54b06692e8a7,0x3a94b800,0x3e7fff)..BO
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f091577,0x800,0x3956800)..BO
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic
Memtest86+ needs a 16-bit boot, that is not available on EFI, exiting
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p8/boot/grub/grub.cfg

An error occurred during the repair.
Error: NVram is locked (Ubuntu not found in efibootmgr). Please report this message to boot.repair@gmail.com

Locked-NVram detected.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks
    for (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    biosdisk fshelp fat exfat ext2 ntfs ntfscomp part_msdos
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:     /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi
                    /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/HP/DI.efi
                    /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
                    /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg
                    /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
                    /efi/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
                    /efi/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
                    /efi/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi
                    /efi/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
                    /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
                    /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:     
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:     /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:      

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:     /efi/boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
                    /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:     /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi
                    /efi/pop/grubx64.efi
                    /efi/Pop_OS-6dee65cd-e402-40fc-b8e6-e28c9dec8f19/vmlinu
                    z.efi /efi/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
                    /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/pop/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p7: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:      

nvme0n1p8: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:     /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p9: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:      

nvme0n1p10: ____________________________________________________________________

    File system:    swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info:

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:    vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:     /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
                    /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p8
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: Lucienne from Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: F.18(15.18) from AMI
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0003,0004
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager    HD(1,GPT,a0959a8d-d457-4c76-afe4-7c1a16d270ba,0x800,0x82000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...&................
Boot0001* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(5,GPT,8ab946cd-87d7-6545-9d2e-958aa76179f2,0x2bad1800,0x96000)..BO
Boot0003* Internal Hard Disk    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x2,0x4)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/NVMe(0x1,00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00)/HD(6,GPT,22c6d891-2c8f-4e31-8dff-54b06692e8a7,0x3a94b800,0x3e7fff)..BO
Boot0004* USB Drive (UEFI) -  USB    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x8,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x3)/USB(5,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1f091577,0x800,0x3956800)..BO

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
c152ec201c37b6e97bbc2207e49d1271   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
345123d1a11fad935d584fa50dbf3b3c   nvme0n1p1/HP/DI.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
fdafb5eece6caeccb788c946a28e6872   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
7b5e70643634fef9ae4c3be43e4c379a   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/BiosMgmt.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/BIOSUpdate/CryptRSA.efi
6488d391f74263c9da3c3d47dffa6212   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/CryptRSA.efi
345123d1a11fad935d584fa50dbf3b3c   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/DI.efi
a5d16d56dc4eb159dfb3d5a0741b9d52   nvme0n1p1/HP/SystemDiags/SysDiags.efi
07a7ced3085173b26c2bd4bdec6f2164   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
d8ebd12190e73aa742a97caa56be7785   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
7eca7c30cae38e440c188f3e9b371a1a   nvme0n1p5/boot/bkpbootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p5/boot/bootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p5/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p6/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p6/BOOT/bootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p6/pop/grubx64.efi
ab181536d22ae00f076d93003180d4d4   nvme0n1p6/Pop_OS-6dee65cd-e402-40fc-b8e6-e28c9dec8f19/vmlinuz.efi
4dd73316109adbd8ab233a8384f5beb7   nvme0n1p6/systemd/systemd-bootx64.efi
3795ef72a4ed0369ca44e711527904bf   nvme0n1p6/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1    : is-GPT,    no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,     not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    not-far
nvme0n1p3    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p4    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p6    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p7    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios
nvme0n1p8    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,    grub2,    grub-install,    grubenv-ok,    update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p9    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,    no-docgrub,    nogrub,    nogrubinstall,    no-grubenv,    noupdategrub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    haswinload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6    : is---ESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p7    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    recovery-or-hidden,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p8    : isnotESP,    fstab-has-goodEFI,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p9    : isnotESP,    part-has-no-fstab,    no-nt,    no-winload,    no-recov-nor-hid,    no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p7    : not--sepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p8    : not--sepboot,    with-boot,    fstab-without-boot,    not-sep-usr,    with--usr,    fstab-without-usr,    std-grub.d,    nvme0n1
nvme0n1p9    : maybesepboot,    no---boot,    part-has-no-fstab,    not-sep-usr,    no---usr,    part-has-no-fstab,    no--grub.d,    nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk identifier: 61C52EB5-07D1-41AE-AD5B-8F6CA6D13042
            Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048    534527  532480   260M EFI System
nvme0n1p2   534528  567295  32768   16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3   567296  691804159 691236864 329.6G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4  691804160  732764159  40960000  19.5G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p5  732764160  733378559 614400   300M EFI System
nvme0n1p6  982824960  986920958   4095999   2G EFI System
nvme0n1p7  999008256 1000202239   1193984   583M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p8  733378560  928690175 195311616  93.1G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p9  928690176  982824959  54134784  25.8G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p10 986920960  994734079   7813120   3.7G Linux swap
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 28.67 GiB, 30784094208 bytes, 60125184 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x1f091577
    Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1  *     2048 60125183 60123136 28.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:30.8GB:scsi:512:512:msdos: USB  SanDisk 3.2Gen1:;
1:1049kB:30.8GB:30.8GB:fat32::boot, lba;
nvme0n1:512GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:INTEL SSDPEKNU512GZH:;
1:1049kB:274MB:273MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:274MB:290MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:290MB:354GB:354GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
4:354GB:375GB:21.0GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:375GB:375GB:315MB:fat32::boot, esp;
8:375GB:475GB:100GB:ext4::;
9:475GB:503GB:27.7GB:ext4::;
6:503GB:505GB:2097MB:fat32::boot, esp;
10:505GB:509GB:4000MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
7:511GB:512GB:611MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;

Free space >10MiB: ______________________________________________________________

nvme0n1: 485710MiB:487797MiB:2087MiB

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                               PARTUUID                            LABEL           PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
└─sda1      vfat    800C-FCDC                           1f091577-01                         UBUNTU 22_0      
nvme0n1                                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1  vfat   8A0B-EAEB                           a0959a8d-d457-4c76-afe4-7c1a16d270ba SYSTEM         EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                             952df0f6-6d10-4460-8073-36c09f045a2d                Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3  ntfs   EAEE2311EE22D61B                    70470715-64c4-483f-9e0d-315ca84251ba Windows        Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4  ntfs   7EA030F8A030B88B                    7ad82310-9890-4930-929d-5e469de5a275 My Files       Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p5  vfat   2261-38E4                           8ab946cd-87d7-6545-9d2e-958aa76179f2 NO_LABEL        
├─nvme0n1p6  vfat   901E-258B                           22c6d891-2c8f-4e31-8dff-54b06692e8a7                 
├─nvme0n1p7  ntfs   F026F02826EFEE12                    64b9a7fe-5d4e-4a32-9b8a-00ea84730181 Windows RE tools Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p8  ext4   948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613 7742623a-3762-4840-8479-2d7f96505eb3                
├─nvme0n1p9  ext4   e35a3ead-216d-4fcd-bd55-04cbe02d1b10 39351909-687d-426f-b806-2c41748f7465                
└─nvme0n1p10 swap   d14b79f3-80dc-44ac-9007-9ba2d1132289 74b9a332-7b92-481c-9afc-59791a996962                

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                        Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1      184.8M  28% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3      163.8G  50% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4          17.7G  10% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5      295.9M   1% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/nvme0n1p6          1.8G   7% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p6
/dev/nvme0n1p7          66.7M  89% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p7
/dev/nvme0n1p8          77.5G  10% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p8
/dev/nvme0n1p9          23.5G   2% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p9
/dev/sda1               25.1G  12% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613 root
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

==================== nvme0n1p6/efi/pop/grub.cfg (filtered) =====================

Pop GNU/Linux   6dee65cd-e402-40fc-b8e6-e28c9dec8f19
Pop GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.19.0-76051900-generic   6dee65cd-e402-40fc-b8e6-e28c9dec8f19
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-8A0B-EAEB
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

=================== nvme0n1p8/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-56-generic   948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-43-generic   948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-8A0B-EAEB
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p8/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p8 during installation
UUID=948b24e5-7f01-4f5e-9964-da6e7b035613 /             ext4    errors=remount-ro 0     1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=8A0B-EAEB  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                               none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p8/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p8: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

        GiB - GB            File                                Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                          1
 417.970718384 = 448.792641536  boot/vmlinuz                                1
 354.329662323 = 380.458577920  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-43-generic              1
 417.970718384 = 448.792641536  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-56-generic              1
 354.329662323 = 380.458577920  boot/vmlinuz.old                            1
 433.850582123 = 465.843515392  boot/initrd.img                             2
 404.111785889 = 433.911726080  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-43-generic           1
 433.850582123 = 465.843515392  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-56-generic           2
 404.111785889 = 433.911726080  boot/initrd.img.old                         1

=================== nvme0n1p8: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 15  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 15  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 15  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Apr 15  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 15  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 19  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 15  2022 41_custom

====================== sda1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sda1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

        GiB - GB            File                                Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                          1
```

Is there any way to fix this?

[Boot devices image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NS60.jpg)

**EDIT:**
I checked the system partition from Windows and all the boot related Ubuntu files are unaffected. Here's the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIZ7.png).

Comment: There does not seem to be one solution. A lot of posts and many cases solved without really knowing why. Have you updated UEFI & NVMe firmware. Check UEFI settings as a few have some way to prevent adding settings for security reasons beyond UEFI Secure Boot. 
C Also run dosfsck or from Windows chkdsk on the ESP (FAT32). Some add a boot parameter to grub.

Comment: @oldfred I checked if there are any updates for the firmware but there wasn't. Plus I'm new to this kinda things so I don't understand some of he things you've recommended. Lastly I want to know if this issue would persist if I try different distros? Thank you for your time.

Comment: It seems to be a system or UEFI issue, not distro specific. And when searching Google, it goes way back. And many things tried, and several days later it worked. Users were not sure what of all the changes they tried worked. Older Mint Solved by totally resetting UEFI.  https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=327158 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325390/locked-nvram-detected

Comment: @oldfred I ran factory default option in UEFI but the issue wasn't resolved. But the grub disappears only after booting into windows. After a fresh install the grub shows up after every restart until I boot into windows. Plus I had dual booted PopOS before and it worked fine. I'm not so sure but I think Windows is the culprit.

Comment: HP seems to require users to go into UEFI settings & set boot order. Normally with every other system using efibootmgr (which grub does) or using efibootmgr yourself resets boot order. Check your UEFI settings and boot order. Either HP's UEFI or HP's version of Windows seems to always reset, so Windows is default boot, otherwise.

Comment: @oldfred After a fresh install ubuntu is automatically on the top of the boot order. But once I boot into Windows, it disappears from the boot order list not move down. Like in the image I referred.

Comment: Before booting Windows go into HP's UEFI settings & change to make Ubuntu entry first in boot order.

Comment: It is first before I boot Windows.

Comment: It may be syncing BCD in Windows with UEFI. Some systems work better to register grub/shim from inside Windows - for those that keep resetting Windows as default
http://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot or `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`

Comment: @oldfred Running this command wouldn't affect windows in any way right?

Comment: It would make Windows second in boot order & will have BCD show boot choices.

Comment: @oldfred It worked!! Thank you so much for your time and patience.

Comment: After a locked NVRAM warning from boot-repair throwing the towing, I tried running the command (with grub rather than shim as I have Secure Boot disables). It ran “successfully”. However, now, nothing boots so I’m left with a PC which doesn’t boot anything. Any suggestions? Did the command really “add an entry” or did it tell the Windows Boot Manager to boot using the grub efi instead?

Comment: @Batwam Have you tried the command oldfred provided without making changes? He explained what it does clearly in this thread

Comment: @TechDash yeah, I typed it and it ran “successfully” but upon reboot,  there was no new entry and even the “Windows Boot Manager” entry failed to boot so I was left with an unbootable PC. I ended up trying all possible solutions to “reset” the NVRAM including removing the CMOS battery to no avail. Eventually, I followed the Dell instructions to reset the RTC by pressing the power button for 20s and after that, boot-repair ran successfully. On reboot, it still wouldn’t boot to Ubuntu though but I manually added an entry in the BIOS Boot Sequence section to the grub efi and finally that worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, where Windows updated and removed my access to the boot screen, and I ran Ubuntu on a liveUSB and BootRepair on that, receiving this error. Before this, I ran through this tutorial in an effort to reinstall GRUB, and incidentally installed grub on an SD card plugged into my computer instead (followed the tutorial below but used the wrong drive (for me sda1). I was blocked out of installing on Ubuntu (for me nvme0n1p5) due to some Blocklist.

https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016528

When the SD card was plugged in and I tried to run Ubuntu now via the BIOS screen (the native version, not the one on the flashdrive), it ran a GRUB terminal, as illustrated in this forum, and I followed the solution in the forum for booting Ubuntu via this forum, specifically finding the grub file in my Ubuntu partition (for me nvme0n1p5, for most people (via other tutorials) sdXY).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/329926/grub-starts-in-command-line-after-reboot

This tutorial allowed me to get into my Ubuntu partition, in which I could run update-grub and boot repair, where the NVRam was no longer locked. I ran it without the SD card plugged in just in case in case that mattered (this isn't really my area of expertise), and after rebooting (again without the SD card) and the GRUB menu showed up again.

I did a few other things in this process, including turning off secure boot in the BIOS menu and restoring defaults, but these did not work for me. They may be relevant to seeing the SD card's grub screen on loading Ubuntu though, which is why I'm including them at the bottom here.